# How do i open a file in a program with batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to open a file that is in a directory down (`folder/file.bat`) but i want to open it in Notepad++ not cmd.exe. And i want to do this without changing the default program.

How would i do this in batch

I've tried this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -%server%\run.bat
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt exactly understand your question. But from what I understood I tried the following.

For me I just tried simply putting the filename as an argument to notepad++.exe
In my example I kept the file in D:\Test\Notepad++.bat and the Test file Test.txt in D:\Test.txt 
I wrote this command and it works for me

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" ..\Test.txt
```

Hope it helps

The link [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) shows the command line arguments which can be passed to notpad++.exe